# Error when using Class::Tangram::Generator on schemas with dates

Tags: perl

When my Tangram schema has the following line

```
datetime => [ qw' lastAccessed ' ],
```

and I use the following line to generate an object based on the Schema

```
my $curObj=$gen->new('User');
```

I get the following error and am not sure how to set the default value of lastAccessed to null.

```
Class::Tangram::Generator: auto-include User failed;
No check function for User->lastAccessed (type datetime);
set $Class::Tangram::defaults{backref} to a sub
    (eg, &Class::Tangram::check_nothing)
    at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/Class/Tangr am/Generator.pm line 195
while trying to import schema for User
    at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/Class/T angram.pm line 2389.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted
    at (eval 920) line 2.  at parse.pl line 59
```

*Edited for clarity.*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will be of any help but there is an outstanding bug with Tangram itself when using NULL DateTime types.... so perhaps related?  See [Tangram issue 26490](http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=26490) for more details.

This bug is still open and is over two years old.  In fact Tangram & Class::Tangram haven't been updated on CPAN since 2006 (there is a development version 2.10_1 of Tangram from Jan 2007).

Still some good news the author/maintainer [Sam Vilain](http://sam.vilain.net/) does have the [code on GitHub](http://github.com/samv/tangram/tree/master) so you could chase him up over there.

Comment: I assume this is the problem, I can always use another ORM in Perl.

Comment: Yes.  If its a pure ORM you need then look at DBIx::Class (http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/).  This is the most used ORM in Perl and i highly recommend it.   However if its Object persistence your after then KiokuDB is what u really need.  Check out this Stackoverflow question for more information on OO Persistence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281803/is-there-an-object-centric-perl-orm